# How to customize beamer's color

Tags: beamer, color

I'm trying to replicate the following colour scheme in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), but am having difficulty in doing so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamercolor*{structure}{bg=PineGreen!20,fg=PineGreen}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50!black!80!black}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary,fg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray!10!white,fg=PineGreen}

\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `PineGreen` try to use some blue color. For example, `blue!20`.

Comment: How to get those colors where? Your question is ambiguous. You have a theme in your sample code and show an image with a very different theme, so it is not clear how the different colors is the image should be translated to the elements of your example code. Please describe exactly what you want to do with the colors in the image with respect to the elements of the theme you use in your example.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I'm just tried to get those colors and set them in that MWE anyhow. I'll organize everything after.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cholor scheme illustrated in the image basically consists  of certain shades of blue and black, so you can replace `PineGreen` in your code with an appropriate shade of blue; for example:

```
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{33,84,157}
```

A little example:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{33,84,157}

\setbeamercolor*{structure}{bg=myblue!20,fg=myblue}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50!black!80!black}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary,fg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=myblue!85,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to take advantage of the fact that the scheme resembles the predefined `whale` color theme, so instead of redefining all the palettes, you can load the color theme and make minor changes to some elements:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=structure!75,fg=white}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]